# How can I store user input on smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to create a smart contract in solidity where I am taking user input from a user which basically is a hash and then I want this hash to be stored on to the smart contract so at the end I could create a function where another user could enter a hash and the program would try to match this hash with the previously stored hash. However, I am not sure how could I store the user's given input on contract?

Comment: Your question may be more suited to another StackExchange site. For questions related to Bitcoin and other cryptocurrencies, please ask on the [**Bitcoin StackExchange**](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com) instead. For questions *specific* to Ethereum, please ask on the [**Ethereum StackExchange**](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com) instead. For further info, please refer to the documentation regarding what is considered [**on-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ethereum smart contracts you have state variables which are stored on the blockchain.
So to store your hash you can create a bytes32 variable and store your user input hash into it.

Example-:

```
contract testContract{
   bytes32 public userHashs;

   function userInput(bytes32 _hash)public {
      userHashs = _hash;
   }

}
```